# Use get_log of selenium library to extract all the logs of a session

Tags: robotframework

In robot framework, I created a python script to use get_log. What i want is to log all console outputs during a whole test or session, is that possible?
My script is as follows:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn


def get_selenium_browser_log():
    selib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary')
    return selib.driver.get_log('browser')
```

Comment: Try doing it, if you get some error then come here.

Comment: What happens when you run that keyword?